# Gradle dependencies - range matching

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

I am trying to add the following dependency to my Gradle build file:

```
compile 'org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.resources:3.10.+'
```

This package depends on a lot of other packages, that are located in the same repository. The problem is that for some reason, Gradle deems them unworthy. Here's an example of the errors I've been getting:

> Could not find any version that matches org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.equinox.common:[3.7.0,3.7.1).
>
> Versions that do not match:
>
> 3.7.0.v20150402-1709

Note that 3.7.0.v20150402-1709 does match [3.7.0,3.7.1)

Some additional technical details:

- I'm working on Gradle v. 2.11.
- This dependency, as well as its' dependencies, are located in the following repository:
  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Edit 1:
Yes, I could just exclude the transitive dependencies and add them with the correct version numbers, but it's such a horrible solution I can't bring myself to write it down. Hoping someone out there has an elegant solution.